# Appium-JAVA Error: unable to load class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.addons.ModelCleanupAddon' from bundle '731'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

[stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysgJ4.jpg) I am trying to run different tests that I have written, through Appium on an Android device, but I am getting the following errors:

> unable to load class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.addons.ModelCleanupAddon' from bundle '731'

or

> unable to load class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.addons.ModelCleanupAddon' from bundle '561'

My code is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
//import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;


 import java.io.File; 
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 //import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 //import org.junit.Test;


 public class CustomerLogin {
         AppiumDriver driver;
         takeScreenshot SC;
         @BeforeClass
           public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
           File app = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\apks\\DropCarOwner-STAGE-v2.1.0-rc.1.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("DeviceName","306SH");
    capabilities.setCapability("PlatformValue", "4.4.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("PlatformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());

    driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
}*/
@Test
public void Login() throws Exception{
    WebElement email= driver.findElement(By.id("com.dropcar.owner:id/editTextEmailAddress"));//com.dropcar.owner:id/editTextEmailAddress
    email.sendKeys("a","w","a","i","s","d","u","r","r","a","n","i","8","7","@","g","m","a","i","l",".","c","o","m");

    WebElement password= driver.findElement(By.id("com.dropcar.owner:id/editTextPassword"));  //com.dropcar.owner:id/editTextPassword
    password.sendKeys("c","h","e","c","k","i","n","g","1","2","3");

    WebElement check= driver.findElement(By.name("Remember me")); //com.dropcar.owner:id/checkBoxRememberMe
    driver.tap(0, check,0);
    //check.click();

    WebElement signIn=driver.findElement(By.name("SIGN IN"));
    driver.tap(1,signIn,1);
    //signIn.click();

    SC.Screenshot(driver);


}

@AfterTest
 public void end(){
    driver.quit();
}


 }
```

I am using Eclipse 4.4.1. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure before running the script appium-doctor command is working successfully. If you will attach the appium log then it will be more easy to tell you the actual solution of your problem.